# h1 not aligning with navigation bar

Tags: html, css

New to HTML/CSS and I'm trying to align the h1 with the navigation bar but it's not working. I want the header and the two navigation links to be on the same line.

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #2eb82e;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-left: 1000px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="navigation">
  <nav>
    <header>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
    </header>
    <ul>
      <li class="main-nav"><a class="link" href="">Nav 1</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav"><a class="link" href="">Nav 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: `header` and `ul` also have to have `display: inline-block`: https://jsfiddle.net/ftj70zhu/2/

Comment: @Raheem you mean the `Nav` should be within `header`? as a `inline`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz yes, the ```Nav``` should be inside the header

Comment: @Raheem I have added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you can do to make it simple:

> 1. Since the `nav` are outside of `header`, you can making `nav` as `position:relative;` so that the `nav` elements will be relative to `header`.
> 2. Then you can make `position:absolute;` to `nav` and made it `top:25px;` since you have your `header` as 50px(half to make it center).
> 3. `Margin-left` is not needed I have removed that as well.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/2tmd4Lv7/7/) to play-around.

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

.links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  /* 25px because your header height is  50px, i made it center align */
  right: 10%;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #2eb82e;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="navigation">
  <nav>
    <header>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
    </header>
    <ul class="links">
      <li class="main-nav"><a class="link" href="">Nav 1</a></li>
      <li class="main-nav"><a class="link" href="">Nav 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need remove `margin-left: 1000px;` in `.main-nav` and set `padding-left` for ul to 0

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #2eb82e;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 0px;       
  line-height: 0px;
  
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

ul{
padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="navigation">
    <nav>
        <header><h1>Heading</h1></header>
            <ul>
                <li class="main-nav"><a class="link" href="">Nav 1</a></li>
                <li class="main-nav"><a class="link" href="">Nav 2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    </section>
```